# Using jest to send text to an input field and update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Working on a technical challenge again. I want to set up unit tests (don't have to, but I would like to).

Problem is when I try to use userEvent or fireEvent  to send some text to an input field, nothing happens (my expect toEqual test fails. I noticed that when I commented out enough of my code to figure out what was going on, I got the error: `TypeError: setUsername is not a function` when I use userEvent to type some text into the input field.

I assumed this meant I would need to create a mock state (setUsername updates the username state). However, this didn't resolve the issue.

The component I am testing is a child of a parent component Index . So I also tried wrapping this child component under the parent component (the username state is passed down to the child from Index). This didn't resolve the issue.

Here's my code:

```
const one = <index>
              <One/>
            </index>

describe("Step One", () => {
    it("Can input text", async () => {
      render(one);
      const mockSetState = jest.fn();
      const component ={
        setState: mockSetState,
        state: {
          username: "test"
        }
      };
      const username = screen.getByTestId("username");
      const email = screen.getByTestId("email");
      await userEvent.type(username, "Emmanuel");
      userEvent.type(email, "emmanuelsibanda21@gmail.com")
      expect(mockSetState).toEqual({"username": "emmanuelsibanda21@gmail.com"});
      // expect(email.value).toEqual("emmanuelsibanda21@gmail.com")
    });
  });
```

This is the code in `Index`:

```
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(null);

  return (
        ...
        {
          steps === 1 ? 
            <One 
              username={username} 
              setUsername={setUsername} 
              steps={steps} 
              setSteps={setSteps}
              setSelectedCountry={setSelectedCountry}
              selectedCountry={selectedCountry}
              setSelectedState={setSelectedState}
              selectedState={selectedState}
              setSelectedCity={setSelectedCity}
              selectedCity={selectedCity}
              email={email}
              setEmail={setEmail}
              profilePic={profilePic}
              setProfilePic={setProfilePic}
            /> ...
        }
```

Here's the code from `One`:

```
export default function One ({username, setUsername, steps, setSteps, setEmail, email, profilePic, setProfilePic}) {
  const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/getPic';

  function changeHandler(e) {
    setUsername(e.target.value)
  }
  function emailChange(e){
    setEmail(e.target.value)
  }
  ...
  return (
    <>
    ...
        <div className={styles.description}>
          <Input 
            data-testid="username"
            onChange={changeHandler} 
            placeholder="What is your full name"
            value={username}
          />
          <Input
            data-testid="email"
            onChange={emailChange}
            placeholder="Please enter a valid email"
            value={email}
          />
        </div>
        {
          username && isEmailValid(email) === true?
          <Button data-testid="next" onClick={ () =>  nextStep() }>Next</Button>
          : null
        }
      </main>
    </>
  )
};
```

Any ideas

Comment: Can you add the sample code for component `One` as well? Will be helpful to debug the issue.

Comment: @EternalObserver Added the code for component `One`

Comment: Thanks. Can you change `userEvent.type` to `fireEvent.change(email, {target: {value: "emmanuelsibanda21@gmail.com"}})`? Also, wrap it inside `waitFor` or `act`.

Comment: one thing - you are missing `await` in line `userEvent.type(email, "emmanuelsibanda21@gmail.com")` - all `userEvent` APIs are async